# Customer Telephone is required, even it is not configured in that store, works after cache clear, for some time

Tags: cache, magento2.3.4, eav

Since several days (we did not make any code changes, besides the recent the CVE-2022-24086 patches), customers in a certain store of multi-website store cannot order, because Magento requires the telephone number, if it is not required in the config.

The problem disappears when we clear all caches, only to resurface again after a some time.

Our config is like this:

```
$ n98-magerun2 config:store:get "customer/address/telephone_show"
+---------------------------------+----------+----------+-------+
| Path                            | Scope    | Scope-ID | Value |
+---------------------------------+----------+----------+-------+
| customer/address/telephone_show | default  | 0        | opt   |
| customer/address/telephone_show | websites | 6        | req   |
| customer/address/telephone_show | websites | 7        | req   |
+---------------------------------+----------+----------+-------+
```

We have the problem in store 7, of website 3, so here the default value "optional" should be used.

When we now push to the API or a customer checks our (there it is the `payment-information` endpoint), we get a 400 error:

```
PUT https://shop.backend.example.com/rest/store_code_of_storeview_7/V1/customers/63

...
                <telephone />
...
```

We get the response:

```
{"message":"Bitte \u00fcberpr\u00fcfen Sie die Informationen zur Lieferadresse. \"telephone\" ist erforderlich. Geben Sie es ein und versuchen Sie es erneut."}
```

Which is the translation for

```
Please check shipping addresses information. "telephone"  is required. Enter and try again.
```

So while we are able to reproduce the problem, we were reading the config:

```
>>> $di->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class)->getValue('customer/address/telephone_show', 'websites', 3);
=> "opt"
>>> $di->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class)->getValue('customer/address/telephone_show');
=> "opt"
>>> $di->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class)->getValue('customer/address/telephone_show', 'websites', 6);
=> "req"
>>> $di->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class)->getValue('customer/address/telephone_show', 'stores', 7);
=> "opt"
```

this is all looking fine.

But still, when we clean all caches, it starts to work again.

It does not seem to be only the config cache.

We cleared the caches step by step already:

```
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean config
config cache cleaned
$ # still not working
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean compiled_config
compiled_config cache cleaned
$ # still not working
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean config_webservice
config_webservice cache cleaned
$ # still not working
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean config_intergration_api
"config_intergration_api" skipped (unknown cache type)
Aborting clean
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean config_integration_api
config_integration_api cache cleaned
$ # still not working
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean config_integration
config_integration cache cleaned
$ # still not working
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean pricesystem_cache
pricesystem_cache cache cleaned
$ # still not working
$ n98-magerun2 cache:clean
config cache cleaned
layout cache cleaned
block_html cache cleaned
collections cache cleaned
reflection cache cleaned
db_ddl cache cleaned
compiled_config cache cleaned
eav cache cleaned
customer_notification cache cleaned
config_integration cache cleaned
config_integration_api cache cleaned
google_product cache cleaned
full_page cache cleaned
config_webservice cache cleaned
translate cache cleaned
pricesystem_cache cache cleaned
vertex cache cleaned
$ # now it works
```

We would try to reproduce it locally by restoring the redis-dump into a dev environment, but I am wondering if anyone has seen such behaviour before?

Magento version is 2.3.4-p2

EDIT: I also checked the eav_attribute table, it's not required:

```
> select is_required from eav_attribute where attribute_code = "telephone"\G;
is_required: 0
```

EDIT2: I seem to be able to reproduce it now.

1. Clean cache
2. Send the payload to a storecode of website 6 (which has telephone_show = req)
3. This returns an error (phonenumber required, which is absolutely correct in this case as per config)
4. Send the same request to store of the other website (not 6 or 7)
5. Still the config is applied, we get an error, but we shouldn't

I currently assume this is some cache key bug.

Answer (score 1):

The reason might be this - still open - Magento bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10978

I found that patch

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e7386e9579adfcd26c64be06070d0cc70b8cebd8

from a closed pull request:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/34856

That did not fully solve the issue.

The above steps (1. push to store with phone = req, 2. push to the other store) work, but if I repeat those steps again, it again does not work.

If I fully disable the EAV cache type, it is all fine.

My current guess it that is is still caching in `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config::cacheUserDefinedAttribute`

There are so many different layers and places of caching, they make your head spin ...

A possible workaround would be to disable the `eav` cache type. Then, the issue is not reproducible. But this might have a negativ performance impact.